# Is it possible to update URL is availability test in application insights through powershell on a schedule task/frequency

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights

I have a number of environments in azure which utilize on-premise Restful services for one of our customers. We currently have application insights configured within a resource group, and an availability test configured to ping a URL at a specified frequency, configured with an insights alert (email when goes down)

An access token is embedded into the URL which needs to be updated frequently. Is it possible to update the URL highlighted programmatically to replace the token (Scheduled/automated basis )

[image]

Just wondering what technologies could be used to update an availability URL on a scheduled basis (every two weeks)

Azure functions?
Some sort of PowerShell script as a scheduled task?
ARM templates using the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/powershell#add-an-availability-test

Any advice on how to proceed with this task efficiently and using the most appropriate technologies would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have to say seems there is no PowerShell module provided to modify the url of App Insight webtest , but we can do it via REST API . Try the PowerShell below :

```
$clientId = "<your Azure AD application ID>"
$clientSec="<your Azure AD application secret>"

$appInsightName ="<your app insight name>"
$webtestName="<your webtest name>"
$subscriptionId = "<your subscription ID>"
$resourceGroupName = "<your resource group name that your app insight in>"
$tenant = "<your tenant name/ID>"

$newUrl = "<the new URL>"

#get access token to fetch details of webtest
$body=@{
    "grant_type"="client_credentials";
    "resource"="https://management.azure.com/";
    "client_id"= $clientId;
    "client_secret" = $clientSec
}

$accessToken=(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.windows.net/$tenant/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body ).access_token
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourcegroups/{1}/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/{2}-{3}?api-version=2015-05-01"
$uri = $uri.Replace("{0}",$subscriptionId).Replace("{1}",$resourceGroupName).Replace("{2}",$webtestName).Replace("{3}",$appInsightName)
$webtestResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $accessToken"}

#modify the url of webtest
$webTestConf = [xml]@($webtestResult.properties.Configuration.WebTest)
$webTestConf.WebTest.Items.Request.Url = $newUrl

#structure request json to update webtest
$locations = $webtestResult.properties.Locations | ConvertTo-Json

$Configuration = $webTestConf.WebTest.OuterXml | ConvertTo-Json 
$Configuration = $Configuration.Replace("\u003c","<").replace("\u003e",">")


$location = $webtestResult.location
$tags = $webtestResult.tags| ConvertTo-Json
$name = $webtestResult.properties.Name
$kind = $webtestResult.properties.Kind


$json = @"
{
"location":"$location",
"tags":$tags,
"properties":{
    "Name":"$name",
    "Enabled": true,
    "Frequency": 300,
    "Timeout": 120,
    "Locations":$locations,
    "Configuration":{"webtest":$Configuration},
    "Kind":"$kind"
    }
}
"@


Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Body $json -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $accessToken";"Content-Type"="application/json"}
```

Except for Azure function, you can use [Azure automation powershell Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook) with [scheduled task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules#creating-a-schedule) to meet your requirement .

Btw, this powershell demo uses service principle to connect to your Azure subscription, make sure your Azure ad application has permission to modify your app insight. If you have anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know . This issue shall not be passed !

Comment: Hi @DamoB , has you change your app insights availability test URL updated successfully ?